# Dual monitor Ubuntu 12.04 - only one monitor works at a time

Tags: nvidia, ati, xorg, multiple-monitors, resolution

Let me preface this by saying I've been searching and hacking at this for a week. I've tried everything that I've ready (that I understand) on the site here and plenty of other sites. I've been a Linux/Ubuntu user for many years but I don't mess with Xorg or video setup in Linux very often so my experience in that area might be a bit lacking. That being said.

**Problem:** I have an HP Compaq desktop with an onboard video card (Intel), an NVidia card, and an ATI card. I can not get more than any one of them to work at a time however they all will work separately. I can change the default boot display in BIOS and change the one that is used but this doesn't do me much good.

**Goal:** I have two monitors and I would like to run them both as an extended setup with two separate desktop spaces that I can use. I would like to run this in GNOME.

I've Tried: All of the different drivers I can find and think of. I don't think this is the problem tho because I can see when I list the devices that they have drivers activated but not used. I've attempted removing all drivers and only installing the XOrg ones, also tried just using Nouveau, just Nvidia, just ATI, etc... combinations of these. The `nvidia-settings` tool says that no drivers are in use so that doesn't do me any good. I've tried `dpkg-reconfigure -phigh xserver-org` which just just puts me back on Unity instead of GNOME. I can't figure out why this happens. If I delete the `xorg.conf` and reboot I do get my GNOME back.

The regular display control panel only shows one display no matter what I've done. The *additional drivers* panel currently has the _nvidia_96_ driver installed. When I try to install the unsupported Nvidia driver it tells me that I have broken packages however I don't believe I do.

I'm not sure what to try any longer and had started trying things randomly so I figured it might be time to reach out for a little help.

Below is some info that I generally see provided in video configuration help threads like mine. Please let me know if I can provide any other info that might help determine what needs to be done here.

Thanks in advance!

Helpful Info:

```
root@flop:~# lshw -C video | grep product
  product: RV370 5B60 [Radeon X300 (PCIE)]
  product: RV370 [Radeon X300SE]
  product: NV18 [GeForce4 MX 4000]

root@flop:~# lspci | grep VGA
07:04.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation NV18 [GeForce4 MX 4000] (rev c1)
20:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV370 5B60 [Radeon X300 (PCIE)]

root@flop:~# xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1600 x 1200, maximum 4096 x 4096
DVI-0 connected 1600x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 367mm x 275mm
   1600x1200      60.0*+
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
S-video disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)


07:04.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation NV18 [GeForce4 MX 4000] [10de:0185] (rev c1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Jaton Corp Device [1b13:0000]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 32 (1250ns min, 250ns max)
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 20
    Region 0: Memory at f8000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Region 1: Memory at e8000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at f9040000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 2
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidia_96, nouveau, nvidiafb

20:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV370 5B60 [Radeon X300 (PCIE)] [1002:5b60] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Device [1002:0f02]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 48
    Region 0: Memory at f0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=64M]
    Region 1: I/O ports at 1100 [size=256]
    Region 2: Memory at f9100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at f9120000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2+ AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [58] Express (v1) Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <128ns, L1 <2us
            ExtTag+ AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE- FLReset-
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal+ Unsupported-
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x16, ASPM L0s L1, Latency L0 <128ns, L1 <1us
            ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot-
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- Retrain- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x4, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 00000000fee0100c  Data: 41b1
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES- TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr-
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr-
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap- CGenEn- ChkCap- ChkEn-
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon, radeonfb

20:00.1 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV370 [Radeon X300SE] [1002:5b70]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Device [1002:0f03]
    Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Region 0: Memory at f9110000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2+ AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [58] Express (v1) Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <128ns, L1 <2us
            ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE- FLReset-
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal+ Unsupported-
            RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x16, ASPM L0s L1, Latency L0 <128ns, L1 <1us
            ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot-
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- Retrain- CommClk-
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x4, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be the onboard video card. I have had some experiences with the same setup, and the onboard video card stops working right after the PCIE / AGP card is installed.

To confirm this, leave the external card installed and just connect the monitor to the onboard card, you won't be able to see anything.

Now, take the PCIE video card off the mobo and the onboard card will work again.

It is a BIOS boundary rather than driver / configuration or ubuntu problem, it won't work on windows neither.

Sorry!

Comment: I thought the same thing as well but notice that I mentioned that I have two video cards in addition to the onboard card now. I feared this was the problem so I added a second and am still having the same issue...

Comment: Just to follow up, I never got this working. I attribute it to older hardware (the video cards) simply not wanting to work with the drivers... Maybe it could be made to work but its not worth the time for me at this point... 

If anyone still has ideas I'd be glad to hear them or help anyone out with my experiences!